# Contact form ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, server-error

I am trying to make a "Contact us" form in my web page, I have tried something and I think it should work but I still get error.

I have tried this:

**HomeController.cs**

```
   public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Contact(ContactModel model, string email, string subject, string htmlMessage)
        {
            using (MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage())
            {

                mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("");
                mailMessage.Subject = subject;
                mailMessage.Body = htmlMessage;
                mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(email));
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Host = "smtp-mail.outlook.com";
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
                NetworkCred.UserName = "myemail@hotmail.com";
                NetworkCred.Password = "myEmailPassword";
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
                smtp.Port = 587;
                await smtp.SendMailAsync(mailMessage);
            }
            return View(model);
        }

        public ActionResult SuccessMessage()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

**ContactModel.cs**

```
public class ContactModel
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

**Contact.csshtml**

```
@model ContactForSpacess.Models.ContactModel


<h2>ContactMail</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Contact</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Message, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Message, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Message, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

I get the following error:
***Server Error in Application. The resource could not be found.
Description: HTTP 404.***

Appreciate all ideas and help I can get!

Thanks.

Comment: Try: `@using (Html.BeginForm("Contact", "Home", FormMethod.Post))`

Answer (score 0):

You've only defined the action which receives the form submission - the HttpPostAttribute means that action cannot be reached by a GET request. Assuming that you want the form you've shown to be a page on your website, you need to define a GET action:

```cs
public ActionResult Contact()
{
    var model = new ContactModel();

    return View(model);
}
```

You can decorate the action with `[HttpGet]` if you want, but it's not really necessary.

You can also update your Razor helper to explicitly specify the form method as POST and to set the action attribute, if need be:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Contact", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
   @* ... your code *@
}
```

As noted by @asawyer, the HtmlHelper.BeginForm extension emits a form with method="post" by default: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Html_FormExtensions_BeginForm_System_Web_Mvc_HtmlHelper_

Comment: Right, the change I commented about wouldn't be needed if this existed.

Comment: @asawyer No, the default method is GET, on the `<form>` element (https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-form-method), so that needs to be done as well. I'll change this to a community wiki if you care to add that to the answer.

Comment: @asawyer I added that bit to the answer, but feel free to elaborate.

Comment: When called with no arguments `.BeginForm` - `Writes an opening <form> tag to the response. The form uses the POST method, and the request is processed by the action method for the view.`  Since there was no Get Home/Contact in the question, it makes sense that it didn't behave correctly. Once you add one, per your response, it should function as expected.  But  you could also just add the action/controller arguments to direct the post. @JanAdams - Use Fiddler or the Network tab in your browsers debugger to help diagnose issues like this. It will show you exactly where the form is posting.

Comment: Ah. The Razor helper emits a form with method="post" by default? Don't know if I knew that at some point or not - I rarely use the empty BeginForm. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

should look like this.

```
 [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Contact()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("postcontact")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ContactMakePost([FromBody] Contact model)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

you view should look like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("postcontact", "Home", FormMethod.Post)){ }
```